# nuxeo 8.10 integration with MarkLogic 8.0-5.8

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, nuxeo

We are having below 3 error in nuxeo log file :

Caused by: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-OPTION: cts:element-reference(fn:QName("","webc__name"), "type=null") -- Invalid option "type=null"
 [Session: user=nuxeouser, cb=nuxeo [ContentSource: user=nuxeouser, cb=nuxeo [provider: address=localhost:8010, pool=1/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/8.0-5, Server: XDBC/8.0-5.8]
on line 5
expr: cts:element-reference(fn:QName("","webc__name"), "type=null")

Caused by: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-OPTION: cts:element-reference(fn:QName("","dc__issued"), "type=null") -- Invalid option "type=null"
 [Session: user=nuxeouser, cb=nuxeo [ContentSource: user=nuxeouser, cb=nuxeo [provider: address=localhost:8010, pool=1/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/8.0-5, Server: XDBC/8.0-5.8]
on line 5
expr: cts:element-reference(fn:QName("","dc__issued"), "type=null")

Caused by: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-OPTION: cts:element-reference(fn:QName("","nt__dueDate"), "type=null") -- Invalid option "type=null"
 [Session: user=nuxeouser, cb=nuxeo [ContentSource: user=nuxeouser, cb=nuxeo [provider: address=localhost:8010, pool=1/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/8.0-5, Server: XDBC/8.0-5.8]
on line 5

Answer (score 1):

cts:element-reference options does not allow for type=null. valid datatypes are:

- int
- unsignedInt
- long
- unsignedLong
- float
- double
- decimal
- dateTime
- time
- date
- gYearMonth
- gYear
- gMonth
- gDay
- yearMonthDuration
- dayTimeDuration
- string
- anyURI
- point
- long-lat-point

Please refer to the docs here:  https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-reference